# How to setup Magento 2 with Docker

Tags: magento2, php, installation, docker, shell

I want to setup Magento 2 with docker and system of containers are ubuntu.

Can anyone help me, how to setup docker file?

Comment: Not worth a full answer, but learn `docker-compose`, its nice and easy for Mage2.

Comment: I have done this for Mac, working perfectly. May be helpful for you.  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268086/how-to-setup-docker-image-for-magento-2-on-mac-book/275161#275161

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've been using for the last 6 months the docker images created by [Fabrizio Balliano](https://github.com/fballiano/docker-magento2) It works nicely on ubuntu. And you have a readme file explaining what you need to do to get it running.

Comment: The project readme says "if someday we'll be able to deploy this infrastructure in production..." This implies it is not production-ready. Is it recommended to run Magento 2 in docker on production servers?

Answer (score 11):

You can use these files to setup your docker environment easy to use, visit link below - https://github.com/markoshust/docker-magento

You can setup on both environments windows and mac. I hope so it will help you.

Comment: I followed this but they do not provide sufficient information for the setup on Linux. Facing challenges with MySQL connection. Most probably due to available ports

Answer (score 3):

I am following Magento Commerce Cloud > [Docker development](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/docker/docker-development.html) > Launch Docker > [Developer mode](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/docker/docker-mode-developer.html) so that I can stay updated with the official Magento docker development.
Working fine in MacOS for me. I have tested both Magento Commerce and Open Source.

In order to work with Open Source version I had to do few tweaking while following [Developer mode](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/docker/docker-mode-developer.html):

1. While you are done with the Step#1

   > Download a Magento application template from the Magento Cloud repository.

   you should get a [composer.json](https://github.com/magento/magento-cloud/blob/master/composer.json) and a [composer.lock](https://github.com/magento/magento-cloud/blob/master/composer.lock) in the directory. You will need to replace those two files with your preferable [composer.json](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/composer.json) and [composer.lock](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/composer.lock) files if you like contributing to the Magento 2 Code Base. Or you may take a copy of those files generated during [installing Magento using Composer](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/composer.html).
2. In Step#5

   > In your local environment, generate the Docker Compose configuration file.

   while running the following command you may get the `ece-docker` not found error:

> $ ./vendor/bin/ece-docker build:compose --mode="developer" --sync-engine="mutagen" --php 7.3
>
> -bash: ./vendor/bin/ece-docker: No such file or directory

In order to solve that you will need to add `magento/magento-cloud-docker`:

```
$ composer require magento/magento-cloud-docker
```

Now you should be able to build the configuration.

You may need to edit the docker.compose.yml file to meet your needs.

3. In Step#10

   > Install Magento in your Docker environment

you should encounter the following error:

> Could not open input file: ./vendor/bin/ece-tools
> Solve that with

```
$ composer require magento/ece-tools
```

4. Follow the rest of the steps accordingly. And you should be done.

Comment: still i'm getting error ./vendor/bin/ece-tools

Comment: @sivakumar What error were you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Magento2 with nginx + varnish
https://hub.docker.com/r/meanbee/magento2-varnish