# How to setup Docker Image for Magento 2 on Mac Book?

Tags: magento2, installation, docker

I want to setup **Docker for Magento 2**.

I have gone through number of links but didn't find the solution yet. Can somebody share useful links to do this.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I figured it out:

**Step 1.** Install Docker

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/

**Step 2.** Clone Docker Image for Magento 2

https://github.com/rhinos-dubai/docker-magento2

or

https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento

or

https://github.com/clean-docker/Magento2 or you can use any other reliable Image.

**Step 3.** I am considering 1st link for image here. Now from terminal go to the folder YourlocalFolderName/docker-magento2 like

> cd YourlocalFolderName/docker-magento2

and run:

> docker-compose up -d

Now go to your web container by this command:

> docker exec -u 0 -it docker-magento2_web_1 /bin/bash

or

> bin/shell

**Step 4.** Now run:

> install-magento

Now type same url in your browser as in env file. Thats it.

If you want to install sample data just run:

> install-sampledata

Push vote up if it was useful for you, so that it may ease the coming readers.

Comment: I tried using this guide, but when I type in `docker exec -u 0 -it docker-magento2_web_1 /bin/bash` I get `No such container: docker-magento2_web_1`

Comment: If you are doing it on Windows, try:  winpty docker exec -u 0 -it docker-magento2-web-1 sh