# Magento 2 + Docker Setup

Tags: magento2.2, docker, ubuntu

Anyone have an idea of how to setup docker in ubuntu 16.04 for Magento2?
Also able to describe docket concept basic will be better.

Thanks

Comment: I have done this for Mac, May be helpful for you, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268086/how-to-setup-docker-image-for-magento-2-on-mac-book/275161#275161

Answer (score 0):

I used this as a basis

https://github.com/meanbee/docker-magento2

Check issues. There are a few workarounds on a couple of bits. I recommend you use persistent storage.

If you've not used docker before check this

https://docs.docker.com/get-started/